# PromQL query to get resources used by daemonset deployed on cluster nodes

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, promql

I would like to see how much memory and CPU are being used by the daemonset deployed over my aks nodes.

Let's focus on memory first.

- I can get the total memory available on my nodes using the `node_memory_MemTotal_bytes` metric
- I can get the deployed damonset list using `kube_daemonset_labels` metric
- I can get the memory used by the containers using `container_memory_usage_bytes` metric

How can I filter only the daemonset in a query like :

`sum(container_memory_usage_bytes) / sum(node_memory_MemTotal_bytes) / count(node_memory_MemTotal_bytes)`

So I can get what percentage of my nodes' memory is being used by the different agents deployed on them.